# how to move left side text into right side text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, yii2

> `I have two text field in front of each other. when i write some text in left side text field. The issue is  how can i move left side text into right side text field through button`

You can view the text field design https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj4Ju.png

Comment: Sorry, your question does not make a great deal of sense and we cannot totally infer the intent from the image alone; we would only be guessing. Please post your current code attempts so far and also consult [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: not clear question

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want just copy the content of the left textarea to the right one, right? Here is a solution in plain js:

```
var
    taLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0],
    taRight = document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0],
    btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];

    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
       taRight.value = taLeft.value;
    })
```

Here is working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5mjcuk0d/)